# Firebase Push Notification often fails in afternoon

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sure you guys find this so weird.

But I did get this problem.
I have tested and found out that only in the afternoon (from 4pm ), I can not get the push notification from firebase

I have tried with postman via FCM or use send test message on firebase console web.
I can only get the push notification in the morning. Even when I do not change the code, I can not get the notification in the afternoon.

Have anyone got this problem before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that I can get FCM only when my app is in background, not when I am in app.

Hope this can help somebody.